# Trying to install scriptcs with brew

Tags: homebrew, scriptcs

```
alessandro@MacBook-Pro ~ % brew install scriptcs
Error: scriptcs: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source scriptcs
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

I'm trying to install `scriptcs` with brew on a MacBook Pro M1 2020, getting this error ^

Any help is greaty appreciated.

Comment: Yeah well, the message is pretty clear: `scriptcs` isn't supported as direct installation, if at all, you can try to fully compile it locally. So what exactly is your question to us?

Comment: @GhostCat Are you referring to the --build-from-source argument? I literally bought a Mac today and I'm trying to use vscode, which requires this package for compiling. So, I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: I guess you will have to do some research then; but I am also pretty sure that there is a way to get VS code to do what you want it to, even on Mac. Maybe you can try whether you can get your stuff via snapcraft ... brew can install the snapcraft package manager, too.